# AWS lambda filtering criteria not filtering out events

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have added filter criteria through web interface to DynamoDB trigger in JSON format:
First one:

```
{"eventName": [ "MODIFY" ]}
```

Second one

```
{"dynamodb":{"NewImage":{"answer":{"S":["Example"]}}}}
```

I also tried something to check if answer exists (as alternative test to answer==Example)

```
{"dynamodb":{"NewImage":{"answer":[{"exists":true}]}}}
```

I see in logs lambda is executed for json where answer is not 'Example' or answer does not exist at all.
What are possible reasons for filter to not work?

Part of event:

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "eventID": "....",
            "eventName": "MODIFY",
            "eventVersion": "1.1",
            "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb",
            "awsRegion": "eu-central-1",
            "dynamodb": {
                "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1661168370,
                "Keys": {
                    "id": {
                        "S": "...."
                    }
                },
                "NewImage": {
                    "createdAt": {
                        "S": "2022-08-22T09:52:39.891Z"
                    },
                    "answer": {
                        "S": "AUT"
                    },
                    ....
```

Comment: I think your problem is specifying these as separate filters. It will pass through payloads that match any of the filters. Instead you need to combine them into a single filter.

Answer (score 0):

This may come as a disappointment to you, unfortunately its not your fault, instead issue with async behavior of Lambda Trigger. Underlying micro-service which registers the filters for trigger, seems like dropping the event filter when they get registered for the first time.

I am hopeful aws lambda team would able to catch up there backlog and fix this bug.

---

### Now the Solution

Follow these steps:

1. Remove the current trigger. (delete it from lambda function console)
2. Add new trigger from the same table with additional settings for filter. (I tried the attribute filtering like below)

```
{"dynamodb": {"NewImage": {"answer": {"S": ["Example"]}}}}
```

3. Deploy and Test.

---