# Use AWS Lambda filtering for dynamo db stream when attribute does not exist not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to filter the AWS lambda invocation based on one of attributes of the Item from DynamoDB. I would like the lambda to run only if the "link" is not existing.
I have Item types:
`{title: "A", description: "This is description", link: "https://google.com}`
and
`{title: "A", description: "This is description"}`.

To filter the lambda invocations I have tried to set it in the following way:
`{\"dynamodb\": {\"NewImage\": {\"link\": {\"S\":  [ { \"exists\": false } ]}}}}`

and

`{\"dynamodb\": {\"NewImage\": {\"link\":   [ { \"exists\": false } ]}}}`

None of these worked, the lambda is invoked independent of the attributes existing.

I found the syntax in AWS Docs: [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html#filtering-syntax)

I also tried to delete the trigger as was suggested in this answer: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73444611/aws-lambda-filtering-criteria-not-filtering-out-events) but that did not help, the lambda still runs in each case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This event filter works:

```
{
    "dynamodb": {
        "NewImage": {
            "link": {
                "S": [
                    {
                        "exists": false
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested by creating the following items:

##### Did not invoke Lambda

```
{
 "pk": "1",
 "sk": "2",
 "link": "B"
}
```

##### Invoked Lambda

```
{
 "pk": "1",
 "sk": "1"
}
```

*Be sure that `links` is a String value, not a List or Map for example, as `exists` only works on leaf nodes*

Comment: Thank you! I have tried again and it worked.